Theme parser errors when running GTK 4 demo code
The page Getting Started with GTK has an introductory GTK 4 code sample. I successfully compiled it. When I run the program, the window appears, but I'm getting a lot of Gtk-WARNING messages to stderr from the theme parser.
(example-0:26609): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:38.895: Theme parser error: gtk.css:1317:51-70: No property named "-gtk-outline-radius"
(example-0:26609): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:38.895: Theme parser error: gtk.css:1517:50-64: Not a valid image
(example-0:26609): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:29:38.895: Theme parser error: gtk.css:1519:59-73: Not a valid image
(many more...)

The pkg-config commands return the following:
$ pkg-config --cflags gtk4
-I/usr/include/gtk-4.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/webp -I/usr/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/graphene-1.0/include -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -pthread 

$ pkg-config --libs gtk4
-lgtk-4 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lvulkan -lgraphene-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 

How do I avoid errors from the theme parser?
Running Ubuntu 24.04, gcc 13.2.0
Thank you.
